# Compute $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \int_3^4 (-x^2+6x-8)^\frac{n}{2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definite-integrals

Compute $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \int_3^4 (-x^2+6x-8)^\frac{n}{2}dx.$$
I am interested in a method to compute this as simply as possible. I know that by DCT this is $0$, but I am not allowed to use it. With the substitution $t=x-3$ I got that this is $\int\limits_0^1 (1-t^2)^\frac{n}{2}dt$ and by using that $e^x\ge x+1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ I could show that the limit is $0$. This is anyway pretty complicated for the level of the exam where this was given, I would be interested in something even easier. Is it possible to write a recurrence relation for instance?
EDIT: Based on Ian's answer I came up with the following solution and I would like to know whether it works:
Let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and $I_n=\int_0^1 (1-t^2)^\frac{n}{2} dt$.
$$I_n=\int_0^{\epsilon}(1-t^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}dt+\int_{\epsilon}^{1}(1-t^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}dt\le \epsilon + (1-\epsilon^2)^\frac{n}{2}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$ 
After we take the limit as $n\to \infty$ we get that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} I_n \le \epsilon, \forall \epsilon \in (0,1)$ and if we now let $\epsilon \searrow 0$ it follows that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} I_n \le0$ and since $I_n\ge 0$ we get that the limit is $0$.
I think this is basically what Ian did, but I would like to know whether it is correct to write it like this.

Comment: One way is to do direct estimation by splitting the domain near $x=3$. Then the integral near $x=3$ is small because you made that region small and the region far from $x=3$ gives a small integral when $n$ is large enough.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, I thought about splitting it into $\int_3^{3+\epsilon} +\int_{3+\epsilon}^4$ for $\epsilon >0$, but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: @ChemistryGeek It should, since $-x^2+6x-8 = -(x-4)(x-2)$ is decreasing from $1$ to $0$ on $[3,4]$. Hence on $[3+\epsilon,4]$, the integrand goes to $0$ uniformly and thus the limit goes to $0$, and on $[3,3+\epsilon]$, the integrand is always bounded... Now you let $\epsilon$ tend to $0$

Comment: @user58955 it does, but I think that we may need to interchange the limits, which is not allowed here.

Comment: @ChemistryGeek As I said, the integrand goes to $0$ *uniformly* on $[3,3+\epsilon]$, and thus you don't need to interchange the limits

Comment: @user58955 You had it slightly backwards in this last comment. Your previous comment was correct, it is uniform on $[3+\epsilon,4]$ and on $[3,3+\epsilon]$ you can use the smallness of the domain.

Comment: @Ian Oh, yes, that was a typo in my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For direct estimation (as opposed to evaluation in terms of special functions followed by estimation as in Claude's answer), your change of variable is convenient for computation. Introduce a parameter $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and write

$$\int_0^1 (1-t^2)^{n/2} dt = \int_0^{\varepsilon} (1-t^2)^{n/2} dt + \int_{\varepsilon}^1 (1-t^2)^{n/2} dt.$$

The first term is less than $\varepsilon$ because the integrand is bounded above by $1$ and the interval is of length $\varepsilon$; the second term is less than $(1-\varepsilon^2)^{n/2}$ for essentially the same reason.

Now tune $\varepsilon(n)$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \varepsilon(n)+(1-\varepsilon(n)^2)^{n/2} = 0$. In particular you find that you need $\varepsilon(n) \to 0$ and yet also $n \log(1-\varepsilon(n)^2) \to -\infty$. For the latter it suffices to have $n \varepsilon(n)^2 \to \infty$. So $\varepsilon(n)=n^{-1/3}$ will work.

Then the squeeze theorem gets you what you want.

You could also have done this without a change of variable, but then it would perhaps not be so obvious that $-x^2+6x-8$ is strictly decreasing starting from $1$ on $[3,4]$, which is really what we used here. Writing it as $1-(x-3)^2$ helps with seeing that.

Comment: based on your answer I could come up with a similar answer, which I added in my post. I would like to know if it is correct to write it the way I did.

Comment: @ChemistryGeek Your approach works here, it's a little bit less reliable than my approach of selecting $\varepsilon(n)$ because you needed it to be possible to control one term solely by sending $\varepsilon \to 0$ and the other term solely by sending $n \to \infty$ so that you could do them in succession. In principle you might need to do them together at some precise rate in a different problem.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am glad that it is all right here. Thank you very much for your solution, it was the most beautiful and elementary and it helped me come up with a version of my own :) .

Answer (score 6):

*May be too complex.*

What you did is good. You end with
$$I_n=\int\limits_0^1 (1-t^2)^\frac{n}{2}\,dt$$ Now, make $t=\sin(u)$ to work with
$$I_n=\int_0^\frac \pi 2 \cos^{n+1}(u)\,du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2 \frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}$$ Now, take logarithms, use Stirling approximation to get

$$\log\left(\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)-\frac{3}{4
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Now, using $a=e^{\log(a)}$
$$\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}=\frac {\sqrt 2 } {n^{1/2}}-\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}}\frac 1 {n^{3/2}}+\cdots$$

Comment: "May be too complex" - at the very least, OP could try establishing the simple recurrence formula satisfied by $I_n$.

Comment: @J.M.isapoormathematician I tried to do that and I posted my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Partial progress on another method : with the substitution $t=\sin u$ we get that $$\int_0^1 (1-t^2)^\frac{n}{2}dt=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^{n+1}(u)du$$
Let $I_n = \int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^{n+1}(u)du$. By IBP we get that $I_n=\frac{n}{n+1}I_{n-2}$.
Now we may write that $I_{2n}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{2n-2}$ and this gives us that $I_{2n}=\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot ...\cdot (2n)}{3 \cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot...\cdot (2n+1)},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and I don't know how to compute this limit. I tried the ratio test, but it failed.

Comment: You could try evaluating $I_0$ and $I_1$ directly, then use your recurrence to produce other members of the sequence, and then conjecture a pattern you could then try to prove inductively.

Comment: @J.M.isapoormathematician I have just added some further progress.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to compute that limit.

Comment: So proceeding with this method basically boils down to showing the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1}=0$; this isn't quite right, you actually need to fuss about even/odd for a bit, but essentially this is it. To do that you can take the logarithm of the partial product (the usual trick) and then you find that the logarithm goes to $-\infty$ which follows from the fact that the harmonic series diverges. Thus the infinite product itself is zero.

Comment: @Ian I see,  this turns out to be even more complicated. All in all, using repeatedly the fact that $e^x \ge x+1$ for any real $x$ seems to be the best way to go at an elementary level.

Comment: @ChemistryGeek Honestly I would say my approach is pretty elementary, as far as questions about limits of sequences of integrals go.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I agree, your approach is also really good for this question. I will most likely accept your answer because even though Claude's answer is great it is, as he himself said, is too complicated.